# Let one row in grid determine grid width, other rows draws outside clipbounds

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

I have a grid that have a fixed position on a canvas. The grid has a border that contains an image that might vary in size.

Now I'm adding a TextBlock underneath the image that will contain a text that might vary in length. The requirement is that regardless of the length of the text the icon shouldn't move on the canvas.

```
<Canvas>
  <Grid Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100">  
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Gray" 
             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Height}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center">
         <Image Source="{Binding TheIcon}" 
                Width="{Binding IconSize}" Height="{Binding IconSize}" 
                Margin="5" />
     </Border>

     <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                Text="A text that is wider than the icon" 
                TextAlignment="Center"/>
   </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

The problem is that when the text gets wider than the icon the width of the grid increases and the icon starts sliding to the right. This could all be solved by setting the HorizontalAlignment="Left" on the border but we want the text centered underneath the icon as it looks some much better.

I have messed around with ClipToBounds="False" and different ways to build the object but I haven't found anything that works. Anyone got some xaml-magic to share?

### Clarification

[image]

Legend
**No text** - the original state
**Undesired state** - this is how it becomes when I just add a row to the grid. The image is moved horizontally away from the specified coordinate
**Desired state** - I want to keep the icon in position while centering the text underneath it

Comment: `<TextBlock Width="{Binding IconSize}"` ??

Comment: Ok, that makes the textblock as wide as the icon which is good. The downside is that it also truncates the text.

Comment: try wrapping the Text `TextWrapping="Wrap"`

Comment: That would make it possible for me to tick the task as done. The users wouldn't be to happy though, as the text would be unreadable with small icons, <24 px. :-)

Comment: then perhaps set a Minimum size also `MinWidth="200"` or what ever value suits your UI

Comment: Don't think it will do it. See the clarification in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force this behavior with a converter to set a -ve Left margin on the TextBlock and set Left Alignment on the image.

Something Like:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:MarginConverter x:Key="MarginConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Canvas>
  <Grid Canvas.Left="50"
        Canvas.Top="100">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="image"
            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Path=Height}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Background="Gray"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
      <Image Width="{Binding IconSize}"
              Height="{Binding IconSize}"
              Margin="5"
              Source="{Binding TheIcon}" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Wider than icon Text">
      <TextBlock.Margin>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MarginConverter}"
                      Mode="OneWay">
          <Binding Path="ActualWidth"
                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
          <Binding ElementName="image"
                    Path="ActualWidth" />
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Margin>
    </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

and `MarginConverter.cs`

```
public class MarginConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    double textWidth;
    Double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out textWidth);
    double imageWidth;
    Double.TryParse(values[1].ToString(), out imageWidth);
    if (Equals(textWidth, 0.0) || Equals(imageWidth, 0.0))
      return new Thickness();
    return new Thickness {Left = imageWidth / 2 - textWidth / 2};
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Could Produce This (I just set the image element to a different size since I did not have any handy images. Image will be starting at 50,50 . Checked with snoop):

[image: Larger Image]

and

[image: Smaller Image]